# How to avoid Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds?

Tags: laravel, facebook-graph-api, charts, facebook-php-sdk

I have a Laravel application in which I integrated PHP graph sdk to use Facebook graph API. I have a stats page, I display number of posts per type, top 3 posts, and some insights metric like "page_post_engagements" ... in moris charts.

this is my controller:

```
public function stats($id,Facebook $fb)
{
    $page              = Page::find($id);
    $page_fb_id        = $page->fb_id;
    $page_access_token = $page->access_token;
    $oAuth2Client      = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($page_access_token)->getValue());
    $nb_photos   = '0';
    $nb_videos   = '0';
    $nb_links    = '0';
    $nb_likes    = '0';
    $nb_comments = '0';
    $nb_shares   = '0';
    $count_posts = '0';
    $startDate   = Carbon::now()->subDays('29');
    $endDate     = Carbon::now();
    $numberOfDays = $endDate->diffInDays($startDate);
    $classement = array();
    $posts = $fb->get('/'.$page_fb_id.'/posts?fields=type&since='.Carbon::parse($startDate).'&until='.Carbon::parse($endDate))->getGraphEdge();
    if(empty($posts))
    {
        $classement = ['total'=>0,'likes'=>0,'comments'=>0,'shares'=>0];
    }
    else
    {
        foreach ($posts as $key => $post) 
        {

            if($post['type'] == 'photo')
            {
                $nb_photos++;
            }
            else if($post['type'] == 'video')
            {
                $nb_videos++;
            }
            else if($post['type'] == 'link')
            {
                $nb_links++;
            }
            $count_posts++;
            $impress      = $fb->get('/'.$post['id'].'/insights?metric=post_impressions_unique')->getGraphEdge();
            $engage       = $fb->get('/'.$post['id'].'/insights?metric=post_engaged_users')->getGraphEdge();
            $classement[] = ['total'=>($engage[0]['values'][0]['value']/$impress[0]['values'][0]['value'])*100,'id'=>$post['id'],'impressions'=>$impress[0]['values'][0]['value'],'engage'=>$engage[0]['values'][0]['value']];
            
        }
        if(is_array($classement))
        {
            asort($classement);
            $tops       = array_slice($classement, -3, 3);
            $start_elem = array_slice($tops, 0, 1);
            $mid_elem   = array_slice($tops, 1, 1);
            $end_elem   = end($tops);
        }
        if($end_elem['id'])
        {
            
            $top1 = $fb->get('/'.$end_elem['id'].'/?fields=id,message,full_picture,source,type,created_time,from{name,picture}')->getGraphNode(); 
            $likes1        = $fb->get('/'.$end_elem['id'].'/likes?limit=1000000')->getGraphEdge()->count();
            $comments1     = $fb->get('/'.$end_elem['id'].'/comments?limit=1000000')->getGraphEdge()->count();
            $shares1       = $fb->get('/'.$end_elem['id'].'/sharedposts?limit=1000000')->getGraphEdge()->count();
        }
        if($mid_elem[0]['id'])
        {
            $top2 = $fb->get('/'.$mid_elem[0]['id'].'/?fields=id,message,full_picture,source,type,created_time,from{name,picture}')->getGraphNode();
            $likes2        = $fb->get('/'.$mid_elem[0]['id'].'/likes?limit=1000000')->getGraphEdge()->count();
            $comments2     = $fb->get('/'.$mid_elem[0]['id'].'/comments?limit=1000000')->getGraphEdge()->count();
            $shares2       = $fb->get('/'.$mid_elem[0]['id'].'/sharedposts?limit=1000000')->getGraphEdge()->count();
        }
        if($start_elem[0]['id'])
        {
            $top3 = $fb->get('/'.$start_elem[0]['id'].'/?fields=id,message,full_picture,source,type,created_time,from{name,picture}')->getGraphNode();
            $likes3        = $fb->get('/'.$start_elem[0]['id'].'/likes?limit=1000000')->getGraphEdge()->count();
            $comments3     = $fb->get('/'.$start_elem[0]['id'].'/comments?limit=1000000')->getGraphEdge()->count();
            $shares3       = $fb->get('/'.$start_elem[0]['id'].'/sharedposts?limit=1000000')->getGraphEdge()->count();
        }
    }
            

    foreach (range(0, $numberOfDays) as $day) 
    {
        $a[] = ['year'=>$endDate->copy()->subDays($day)->format('Y-m-d')];
    }

    foreach (array_reverse($a) as $key => $value) 
    {
        $page_fans = $fb->get('/'.$page_fb_id.'/insights?metric=page_fans&since='.Carbon::parse($value['year']).'&until='.Carbon::parse($value['year'])->addDays('2'))->getGraphEdge()[0]['values'][0]['value'];
        $fans[]    = ['year'=>$value['year'],'value'=>$page_fans];

        $page_post_engagements = $fb->get('/'.$page_fb_id.'/insights?metric=page_post_engagements&since='.Carbon::parse($value['year']).'&until='.Carbon::parse($value['year'])->addDays('2'))->getGraphEdge()[0]['values'][0]['value'];
        $post_engagements[]    = ['year'=>$value['year'],'value'=>$page_post_engagements];

        $page_impressions = $fb->get('/'.$page_fb_id.'/insights?metric=page_impressions&since='.Carbon::parse($value['year']).'&until='.Carbon::parse($value['year'])->addDays('2'))->getGraphEdge()[0]['values'][0]['value'];
        $impressions[]    = ['year'=>$value['year'],'value'=>$page_impressions];

        $page_actions_post_reactions_like_total = $fb->get('/'.$page_fb_id.'/insights?metric=page_actions_post_reactions_like_total&since='.Carbon::parse($value['year']).'&until='.Carbon::parse($value['year'])->addDays('2'))->getGraphEdge()[0]['values'][0]['value'];
        $post_reactions_like_total[]            = ['year'=>$value['year'],'value'=>$page_actions_post_reactions_like_total];
        
        /*$page_engaged_users = $fb->get('/'.$page_fb_id.'/insights?metric=page_engaged_users&since='.Carbon::parse($value['year']).'&until='.Carbon::parse($value['year'])->addDays('2'))->getGraphEdge()[0]['values'][0]['value'];
        $engaged_users[]    = ['year'=>$value['year'],'value'=>$page_engaged_users];
        
        $page_views_total = $fb->get('/'.$page_fb_id.'/insights?metric=page_views_total&since='.Carbon::parse($value['year']).'&until='.Carbon::parse($value['year'])->addDays('2'))->getGraphEdge()[0]['values'][0]['value'];
        $views_total[]    = ['year'=>$value['year'],'value'=>$page_views_total];*/

    }
    /*$fans_total                = end($fans)['value'];
    $moyenne_interaction       = array_sum(array_column($engaged_users,'value'))/count(array_column($engaged_users,'value'));
    $average_interaction       = array_sum(array_column($engaged_users,'value'))/count(array_column($engaged_users,'value'))/(end($fans)['value']);*/
    $fans                      = json_encode($fans);
    $post_engagements          = json_encode($post_engagements);
    $impressions               = json_encode($impressions);
    $post_reactions_like_total = json_encode($post_reactions_like_total);
    /*$engaged_users             = json_encode($engaged_users);
    $views_total               = json_encode($views_total);*/
    return view('stats',with(compact('randon','id','tasks','page','fans','impressions','post_engagements','post_reactions_like_total','engaged_users','views_total','nb_photos','nb_videos','nb_links','count_posts','fans_total','top1','likes1','comments1','shares1','top2','likes2','comments2','shares2','top3','likes3','comments3','shares3')));
}
```

Is there a way to optimize my code so I can get a better response time and especially avoid the Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds exception?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced#fieldexpansion

Comment: Don’t expect `limit=1000000` to work though, you can not just go as high as you want with that. Different endpoints have different maximum limit values, but none of them nearly as high as 1000000 - you will have to use pagination at some point, if you need all data. But you don’t need to request all individual objects for comments, reactions and likes, if you are just interested in the number - those endpoints offer a `total_count`!

Comment: i tried this query $likes1 = $fb->get('/'.$end_elem['id'].'?fields=likes.summary(true)')->getGraphNode(); but i don't get summary in the result

Comment: That is correct syntax, you can try it in Graph API Explorer. Not sure if getGraphNode is the right method to access this data though. likes etc. are Edges, not Nodes - so try getGraphEdge.

Comment: i already tried it at graph explorer and it worked when i use getGraphEdge i get this error Unable to convert response from Graph to a GraphEdge because the response does not look like a GraphEdge. Try using GraphNodeFactory::makeGraphNode() instead.

Comment: Try some other methods of the FacebookResponse class, such as getDecodedBody, and var_dump the result to see what you get.

Comment: when i used var_dump i saw the summary(total_count) !! what's the problem then ?

Comment: i think the summary is sent as metadata is there a way to access it ?

Comment: Depending on what object type you are dealing with (var_dump shows that as well), it might be in a private class property or something, so that it can’t be accessed from the outside. In that case you’ll have to find out what the appropriate class method to access it is. Not sure how exactly, haven’t used the PHP SDK myself in a while ... have a look in the source code, that should help to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming to get the API data and parse it... it is taking longer than 10 seconds?

You have 2 things to do to improve your system: 1) Use Cache 2) Use Queues.

1. Cache! (Save the API/parsed result for 15 minutes or so)
2. Queues! (API parsing is done in the server background)

---

Your system workflow will be:

1. User hits `/stats`
2. Is there a cache version? Use it. Response time ~ barely 500ms.
3. No/Expired cache? Fire a Queued Job to get the new API data.
4. Show the user 'Data is being refreshed!' and display the latest cache.

Comment: i'm getting all my data from graph request can i just do this ?                        $post = $fb->get('/'.$post_fb_id.'?fields=id,message,created_time,full_picture,from{name,picture}')->getGraphNode();
        Cache::put('post',$post);

Comment: Yes. But `post` will be your cache key... better to be like `Cache::put('post'.$user->id,$post);` so you won't get conflicts or other users see either other caches.

Comment: ah i get it like this Cache::put('post'.Auth::user()->id,$post); ?

Comment: Yeah. There will be no conflict then.

Comment: i did this test code : Cache::put('post'.Auth::user()->id,$post);
        if( Cache::has( 'post'.Auth::user()->id ) ) 
        {
          return Cache::get('post'.Auth::user()->id);
        } but nothing is returned

Comment: This might be dumb but are you sure $post is not empty? Try a normal string. Or try to use Cache using the closure way. e.g. `return Cache::remember(..., function(){});`

Comment: i figured out the problem it was missing the time parameter

Comment: So I think your problem is resolved now. Coupled with Queuing, you'll no longer get timeouts and your app will be extra smooth. If you liked me method, please mark my answer as correct! Thanks.